# Android - How to pass cookie to load url with webview?

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have to load url in webview with sending some cookies. HOw to achieve this ?

I am doing following code..

```
CookieManager cookieManager;

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(PrivacyActivity.this);
cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

cookieManager.setCookie("param", "value");
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});
wv.loadUrl("https://example.com");
```

But not getting proper result. Just getting "https://example.com" as it is. Cookie does not works..

Answer (score 14):

This solution works for me (Just add cookies to the CookieManager before loading the url and that's all):

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
...
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("http://example.com/", "key=value");
webview.loadUrl("http://example.com/");
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved problem as,,,

```
        WebView webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.wv_file);
        final WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(ActivityName.this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        String cookieString = "param=value";
        cookieManager.setCookie(domain_of_url("like http://abc-site.com"), cookieString);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

        Map<String, String> abc = new HashMap<String, String>();
        abc.put("Cookie", cookieString);
        webview.loadUrl("http://abc-site.com/a1/namedFolder/file",
                abc);
```

Comment: what is the alternate for CookieSyncManager ?
Also, do  we need to add  cookie manually? Can't we pass all cookies have to webview?

Comment: @Mr.India `CookieManager` now has a `flush()` method, which blocks until all cookies are sync'ed to disk.