# Passing Session details from android to php

Tags: php, android, session, cookies

I have created an android app, which has a native login page. the login credentials gets authenticated using a php webservice. 
after login user gets redirected to a webview to view the page/dashboard.

But the dashboard.php checks for session variables have been set or not!

so how do i create session variables from native android app and pass it to the webview so as to get to the redirected page?i:e dashboard.php which checks for session variables

**i tried using cookies but still no luck!**

Comment: share a unique id in JSON/XML for each request and response between android and php...this id will regenratewhen user logs in and destroyed when logs out. In this way you can share id between calls and save it in database till the session is on

Comment: @Mangesh Sathe IND  the webservice is already defined the service work for webpage and i need to use the same service in android app so cannot use unique id's nor change the way it functions..need to use sessions anyhow

Answer (score 0):

@deepen saha

Yes you can do it easily

```
String urURL= Url + "?data=" + theString;
webView.loadUrl(urURL);
```

and then use standard javascript to parse window.location.search to get the data.

Comment: you are basically setting a variable using get method

Comment: @deepensaha yes buddy I know its not secure but easy way

Comment: but my question is to create session variables

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass Cookie Value in Webview. so that it can have session like browsers.

please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22657055/942224

Comment: i tried to pass the cookies but nothing happened it redirected me to login page instead

Comment: @deepensaha could you please post your code snippet for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use CookieManager. I had same use-case like yours and it did the trick! I did authentication via UrlConnection and php. 
These lines takes cookies from urlConnection and passes them to WebView.

`android.webkit.CookieManager cookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.flush();`

Comment: @deepen saha Did you try it?